# My log file is empty

Tags: java

The problem with the code below is that, after running the application, "log.txt" is empty. Why?
I looked over the code, but i can't find something wrong.
    package Main;

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class JavaApp1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("log.txt");
        PrintWriter Log = new PrintWriter("log.txt");

        int Line = 1;

        Scanner ScanCycle = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Cate numere doriti sa fie afisate?");
        int Cycle = ScanCycle.nextInt();

        Scanner ScanRange = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Care este numarul maxim dorit?");
        int Range = ScanRange.nextInt();

        Random Generator = new Random();
        for (int idx = 1; idx <= Cycle; ++idx){
            int Value = Generator.nextInt(Range);
            Log.println("(" + Line + ")" + "Number Generated: " + Value);
            Line = Line + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use Java naming conventions; the code is hard to read to seasoned Java devs. Also, you don't flush, nor close, your `PrintWriter`.

Comment: PrintWriter auto closes with println if the PrintWriter gets a true boolean to the left of it. Definitely needs to release the resource too outside below the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to flush your character stream out. Call `close()`[which internally calls `flush()`] or `flush()` on your `PrintWriter` instance.

```
    PrintWriter log = new PrintWriter("log.txt");
    //your code
    log.close();
```

Comment: Likewise you can try with resource try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("this.txt")) { /// code } Try with resource disposes correctly every single time

Comment: Point in to flush out the stream which can be done directly by calling flush, closing the stream. In case of try with resource JVM takes care of closing the stream thereby calling flush on it.

Comment: I tried it earlier but i had an error with the line "PrintWriter log = new PrintWriter("log.txt");", now it's seems to work. Thank you.